# How to pre-fill mat-select value after fetching data from server when editing an object

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

My question is about Angular's reactive forms. I am retrieving form data from a remote server through an API call. With the help of reactive forms, I can map the data to that form as well, but I am not able to display the value on the mat-select element, but when I submit the form, the value of that select element shows. How would I be able to display the correct value when the data is retrieved from an API? I would really appreciate the help. Please see attached link to a screen shot and my code example below.

[Screenshot front-end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhxtC.jpg)

HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="officeForm">
 <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
   <mat-select placeholder="State" formControlName="state">
     <mat-option>None</mat-option> 
     <mat-option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state">
       {‌{state}}
     </mat-option>        
   </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

TS

```
officeData: any;
states: string[] = [Alabama, California, .... etc];
officeForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
 address_1: ['', Validators.required],
 address_2: ['', Validators.required],
 city: ['', Validators.required],
 state: ['', Validators.required],
 zip: ['', Validators.required],
 manager: ['', Validators.required],
 phone: ['', Validators.required],
 notes: ['']
});
```

constructor(
       private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
       private officeService: OfficeService,
       private router: Router,
       private fb: FormBuilder) {}

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
         this.id = params['id'];
         this.officeService.getOfficeWithId(this.id)
         .subscribe(data => {
           this.officeData = data.body.result;
           console.log(this.officeData);`enter code here`
           this.officeForm.patchValue({
             address_1: this.officeData.address_1,
             address_2: this.officeData.address_2,
             city: this.officeData.city.toUpperCase(),
             state: this.officeData.state.toUpperCase(),
             zip: this.officeData.zip,
             manager: this.officeData.manager,
             phone: this.officeData.phone,
             notes: this.officeData.notes,
           });
       });
  }); 
}
```

[Screenshot front-end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhxtC.jpg)

Comment: Nested subscribe calls are dangerous

Comment: @Jota Toledo, thanks for the feedback, any suggestions how I should be writing this particular code? The app is in its very initial stages right now and a lot of refactoring is needed. But I would like to grasp all the good ideas to make my code as lean as possible.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it cannot match value **"california"** to any of values from the **states** array, maybe because in array you have **"California"** starting from uppercase letter.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you Amir, I was stuck on this for a few days and couldn't understand why any of the solutions aren't working. I can't believe it was such a simple fix. I really appreciate you taking some time out and helping me with my query.

Comment: @TejpartapGill So did it help you?

Comment: yes, it did help. I was using the following: state: this.officeData.state.toUpperCase(). Thas where the problem was. So i removed toUpperCase() and it worked without any issues.